Photonic classical and quantum computing
How different is the hardware used for classical and quantum photonic computers? Are there any proposals on hybrid platforms? I'm curious why I never heard of both within the same context, except for the wiki page on classical optical computing using the image for the quantum CNOT gate.

a bit hard to answer without further details. What exactly do you have in mind talking about "classical photonic computers" and "quantum photonic computers"?
